# iOS - UIDatePicker change shown date dynamic

Tags: ios, objective-c, date, uidatepicker, datecell

I am using code from [DateCell example](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/DateCell/Introduction/Intro.html) and I want to change date at start to date which I choose (I load from somewhere). So I am changing value of date in `dataArray` (dictionary with `kTitleKey` and `kDateKey`) and in `dateCell` it's okay. There is shown my date but when I clicked on that cell `DatePicker` is shown and in there is default date from StoryBoard. I guess the problem is in updateDatePicker method:

```
- (void)updateDatePicker
{
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil)
    {
        UITableViewCell *associatedDatePickerCell = [datePickersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.datePickerIndexPath];
        /*
        if (associatedDatePickerCell == nil) {
            associatedDatePickerCell = [datePickersTableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:kDatePickerID];
        }*/
        UIDatePicker *targetedDatePicker = (UIDatePicker *)[associatedDatePickerCell viewWithTag:kDatePickerTag];
        if (targetedDatePicker != nil)
        {
            // we found a UIDatePicker in this cell, so update it's date value
            //
            NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[self.datePickerIndexPath.row - 1];
            [targetedDatePicker setDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey] animated:NO];
        }
    }
}
```

For some reason associatedDatePickerCell is always nil. I tried to change it (with code in comments) but it didn't help (associatedDatepickerCell then wasn't nil but date still wasn't changing). I have the right date in `itemData`.

Edit: added code for `cellForRowAtIndexPath`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = nil;

    NSString *cellID;

    if ([self indexPathHasPicker:indexPath])
    {
        // the indexPath is the one containing the inline date picker
        cellID = kDatePickerID;     // the current/opened date picker cell
    }
    else
    {
        // the indexPath is one that contains the date information
        cellID = kDateCellID;       // the start/end date cells
    }
    //if ([self indexPathHasDate:indexPath])
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];

    // if we have a date picker open whose cell is above the cell we want to update,
    // then we have one more cell than the model allows
    //
    NSInteger modelRow = indexPath.row;
    if (self.datePickerIndexPath != nil && self.datePickerIndexPath.row < indexPath.row)
    {
        modelRow--;
    }

    // proceed to configure our cell
    if ([cellID isEqualToString:kDateCellID])
    {
        NSDictionary *itemData = self.dataArray[modelRow];

        // we have either start or end date cells, populate their date field
        //
        cell.textLabel.text = [itemData valueForKey:kTitleKey];
        UILabel *custLabel = (UILabel*)[cell viewWithTag:2];
        custLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey]];
        UIView *dateView = (UIView*)[cell viewWithTag:3];
        [dateView.layer setBorderWidth:1];
        [dateView.layer setBorderColor:[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]];
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = [self.dateFormatter stringFromDate:[itemData valueForKey:kDateKey]];
    }

    [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: If associatedDatePickerCell is always nil, then the problem is not in the code you posted. You should log both self.datePickerIndexPath and datePickersTableView to see what they return. Either one of these is nil, or you're trying to access a cell that's not currently being displayed in the table view.

Comment: datePickerIndexPath and datePickersTableView is okay. I guess the problem is that cell is not currently displayed but is going to. The problem is I want to set it before is't displayed.

Comment: Then you need to change itemData without referring to the cell. I don't know why the sample code you're working from does it the way it does -- if you have the indexPath, then you should change that item in the array directly without referring to the cell.

Comment: I am changing it. In viewDidLoad I call method which fill all fields and which set itemData with right Date. I got right date there but when datePicker is shown there is still date from storyboard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Who is calling your `updateDatePicker` method?

The problem is that in its implementation you try to get the cell with `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` which may, or may not return a cell depending on the timing, the scrolling position, etc:

> Return Value
>
> An object representing a cell of the table or nil if the cell is not visible or indexPath is out of range.

You should update the picker when returning the corresponding cell in the `tableViewDataSource`, that is inside your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, which will be called lazily by the table view only when needed.

Comment: It was in DateCell example I mention above. You've been right. When I move code from `updateDatePicker` method to `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I get what I want. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that your's `cellForRowAtIndexPath` has code that looks like:

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
```

And you have registered class or nib calling tableViews methods (in viewDidLoad for example):

```
– registerNib:forCellReuseIdentifier:
– registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:
```

So the actual problem in yours `cellForRowForIndexPath:`.

Comment: I don't think there is a problem in 'cellForRowForIndexPath'. In that method I just set right information to DateCell not DatePickerCell.

Comment: But you said that `For some reason associatedDatePickerCell is always nil.` `cellForRowAtIndexPath` always has to return cell, no matter what.

Comment: I added code which I haven in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. I added break point to line with  `cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];` and I get cell for `kDatePickerID`. The weird thing is that I get to this break point after calling `[datePickersTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:self.datePickerIndexPath];`. So first I get nil in `associatedDatePickerCell` and after few Step over I stop at break point in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.